# java Slick 2D how to set color

Tags: slick2d

I'm getting crazy trying to draw a very simple rect and a text in order to just understand how it works with the slick 2d java library.

This is what I try:

```
g.setColor(Color.green);
g.fillRect(50, 50, 50 ,50);

g.setColor(Color.orange);
g.drawString("Write something", 100, 100);
```

I just got to have everything I draw either in green or orange, but not one green and the other orange, as I would like to do...

Can someone help me to figure this out ???

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Your code seems to be correct, and works on my test-game.
Are you running it in the appropriate method, public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g)?

Try to update your LWJGL and Slick2D libraries too.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you're drawing the screen by hand. You pick up a green pen, and you draw a rectangle. Then you pick up an orange pen and draw the words. That's what you're telling Slick2D to do with your code. Don't change colors between the two drawing operations - just set the color, then draw both objects and they will come out as the same color.

When you change colors all shape/text operations you do after that will be in that color, until you change colors again.

Answer (score 0):

I was also importing the `java.awt.Color;`, this library is incompatible with `Slick2D`.

To fix this replace the line `import java.awt.Color;` with `import org.newdawn.slick.Color;`.